# Testing Tools For Simulating User Interaction - Especially Map Panning

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can anyone suggest any tools that can simulate users panning around in a map?  I have used tools such as SoapUI to do load testing, but never anything to simulate users.

In case it matters, the app I will be testing is based on ESRI Javascript API.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to test map panning?

Comment: Trying to reproduce some reported bugs with ui elements (ex:  info window gets 'frozen', another has to do with incomplete rendering of dynamic map service layers).  One of the common factors between several of these bugs is frequent map panning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [DOH Robot](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/util/dohrobot.html). I have not used it with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript but it's the only tool that I know of that is suited for this task (that's not to say there aren't others out there...). Earlier this week I published a [blog post on using DOH](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/05/21/writing-unit-tests-for-your-arcgis-api-for-javascript-apps/) (but not the DOH Robot) with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript which might be of interest as well.

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't used it much, perhaps Selenium (http://seleniumhq.org/) is worth a shot. When playing with it, I found it quite clunky and not all that intuitive, but for testing browser interaction with javascript enabled, then I haven't found too many other options.

I would suspect with most tools though, you would have to write the javascript that simulates the users movements, which I would imagine is a decent sized job in itself, the test runner will then run that code.

I would also love to know if there are better tools out there.